# Can I use 'Cached Exchange Mode' for additional mailbox in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I have two mailboxes configured in my Outlook 2007. I have also enabled 'Cached Exchange Mode' in my account setting.

While the primary mailbox works fine, the 'Offline folder' in my additional mailbox always contains zero items. Hence it's very slow to manipulate with it.

Can someone tell me what's wrong here or how to debug this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I can't. Need to upgrade to Outlook 2010.